# Regex: don't match if string contains whitespace

Tags: ruby, regex

I can't seem to figure out the regex pattern for matching strings only if it doesn't contain whitespace. For example

```
"this has whitespace".match(/some_pattern/)
```

should return `nil` but

```
"nowhitespace".match(/some_pattern/)
```

should return the MatchData with the entire string. Can anyone suggest a solution for the above?

Comment: are you trying to determine if a string contains whitespace, or if a string contains a certain pattern but ONLY if there no whitespace?

Comment: Basically I want match to return nil if the string contains whitespace .

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In Ruby I think it would be

```
/^\S*$/
```

This means "start, match any number of non-whitespace characters, end"

Comment: Ahh! I was missing the end of line anchor at the end. Cheers!

Comment: @Bart, note that `\n` and `\r` are also considered white space characters.

Comment: You might want `/\A\S*\Z/` instead, as this will match the start and end of the string rather than the start and end of lines. `"lineone\nlinetwo"` matched with `/^\S*$/` will return `"lineone"`

Comment: I won't have to worry about multi-line strings in my application but that's an excellent point - thanks.

Comment: What about /^\S*$/m, where m turns on a multiline mode? :)

Comment: This saved me for a pretty weird Regular Expression for PHP and Javascript. In it, I had to match everything if it didn't had any whitespaces OR only match the first 1-3 non-whitespace characters. This is the result: `/^(?:(\S{1,5})\S*|(.{1,3}).*)$/`. It's ugly, I know. And it requires the replacement string `'$1$2'`, but it works fine for the purpose!

Answer (score 4):

You could always search *for* spaces, an then negate the result:

```
"str".match(/\s/).nil?
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>> "this has whitespace".match(/^\S*$/)
=> nil
>> "nospaces".match(/^\S*$/)
=> #<MatchData "nospaces">
```

`^` = Beginning of string

\S = non-whitespace character, `*` = 0 or more

`$` = end of string

Answer (score 3):

Not sure you can do it in one pattern, but you can do something like:

```
"string".match(/pattern/) unless "string".match(/\s/)
```

Comment: +1 for thinking about the question differently... the question could be interpreted as match a string containing pattern 'x' as long as the string does not include whitespace...

Answer (score 1):

```
   "nowhitespace".match(/^[^\s]*$/)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
/^\S*$/
```

That says "match the beginning of the string, then zero or more non-whitespace characters, then the end of the string." The convention for pre-defined character classes is that a lowercase letter refers to a class, while an uppercase letter refers to its negation. Thus, `\s` refers to whitespace characters, while `\S` refers to non-whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

`str.match(/^\S*some_pattern\S*$/)`